How to Add an Observer to Detect Dark and Light Mode Changes Dynamically in macOS?
I need to add an observer to detect changes between dark and light modes dynamically in my macOS app. I have tried using NotificationCenter with NSApplication and an observer method, but I'm unsure how to properly implement it to handle these changes. Could someone provide a solution to detect the appearance changes and handle them accordingly?
class AppearanceManager: ObservableObject {



    static let shared: AppearanceManager = AppearanceManager()



    init() {



        // Observe changes in the appearance

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(

            self,

            selector: #selector(didChangeAppearance),

            name: NSApplication.,

            object: nil

        )

    }



    @objc private func didChangeAppearance() {

        print(schemeReader())

    }



    deinit {

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }

}



func schemeReader() -> String {

    if NSApplication.shared.effectiveAppearance.name == .darkAqua {

        return "dark"

    } else {

        return "light"

    }

}


Given link tries to solve the issue using swiftUI tools, which is not what I want to do, in my code and approach there is no swiftUI approach to solve it and it is just swift, I think this question should not be closed, and it is not duplicated either.

@Sweeper - this question isn't about SwiftUI, it's for AppKit.

You can find the answer in Apple's documentation: Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface. It covers iOS and macOS and includes AppKit code showing how to listen to changes to NSApp.effectiveAppearance. I believe that it what you want.
